# How to apply click event to deeply-nested component

Tags: angular, angular-material

I have a file named frame.component.html:

```
<md-sidenav-container>
    <md-sidenav #sidenav align="end">Jolly good!</md-sidenav>

    <site-header></site-header>

    <div class="site-content">
        <router-outlet></router-outlet>
    </div>

    <site-footer></site-footer>
</md-sidenav-container>
```

In this file I load , header, site-content and footer.

site-header.component.html:

```
<header>
    <div class="header-inner">

        <h1 class="logo">MyWeb<span>Exile</span></h1>

        <site-menu></site-menu>

    </div>
</header>
```

menu.component.html:

```
<div class="menu">

    <ul>
        <li><a [routerLink]="['/home']" [routerLinkActive]="['active']">Home</a></li>
        <li><a [routerLink]="['/blog']" [routerLinkActive]="['active']">Blog</a></li>
        <li><a [routerLink]="['/contact']" [routerLinkActive]="['active']">Contact</a></li>
    </ul>

    <ng2e-dropdown addClass="search">
        <i class="material-icons">search</i>
        <div class="content">
            <searchbar-small></searchbar-small>
        </div>
    </ng2e-dropdown>

    <button md-button (click)="sidenav.open()">
        <md-icon svgIcon="menu"></md-icon>
    </button>

</div>
```

The Sidenav Toggle button didnt work on this place. I read alot of passing the functionality into my menu component. I try it with @output and @input and @viewChild. My problem is that i dont know much about JavaScript. A friend telled me that i need to write a Service for that. But i have no idea how i write it.

Maybe anyone can help me with that? I think this will help alot other people to.

Comment: Yes, you should look into a service, which helps communicate between components without relying on parent-child binding. Don't expect someone to write one for you, though. Take a shot and come back with a more specific question.

Comment: Thanks! Can you share me maybe a service who do this? looked for one allready..

Comment: Angular cookbook has examples for a service to manage component interaction https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/cookbook/component-communication.html

Comment: They talk about "Parent and children communicate via a service" but i want a service that make functions globaly available. Is this possible to in this way?

Comment: You create the service which is called from your parent component.  The children components then listen for events i.e subscribe to a certain function in your service.  When the parent passes a value to that function the children will retrieve it.

Comment: Ya... Sorry, but i tryed last 4 days to understand the Documentation, i googled alot... I think its better when i find a freelancer for this. My javascript skills are so bad... you wont belive. I am a very great at Html, Scss and Designing. but i didnt understand the simpelst Js code. Thanks anyway for trying to help me!